# SGDRegressor float overflow

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to fit a  SGDregressor sklearn for a dataset of 20000 rows. 10 columns are features.

It doesn't seem to be big enough to cause

```
ValueError: floating-point under-/overflow occurred.
```

Why is it happening? What could be possible ways to solve this issue?

Comment: DId you normalize the data?

Comment: I only removed all string parameters and converted to 0 and 1 format. How could other things help? The data frame looks small. Why memory problems?

Comment: I have read about normalization by calculating the standard scores. Yeah, I will try to reduce data in this way

Comment: This is not memory problem, this is scale problem. under/overflow happens when you require very small / large numbers to store in memory, and this might happen if you do not normalize your data (both inputs and outputs). For example, if you fit linear model to predict number 10^10 from numbers of scale 10^-5 you need weights of size 10^15.